# How to handle nested observables

Tags: angular, rxjs5

This code works for me but am wondering if this is better way of handling the nested subscribes. Am fetching an array which I need to loop over and use in another http call. Is this efficient?

```
this.storeService.fetchStores(this.currentCoordinates).subscribe(nearestStores => {
           nearestStores.forEach(store => {
                this.stockService.fetchStockResults(ean, store.id).subscribe(stock => {
                    this.stockResults.push({
                        storeObject: store,
                        ean: stock.ean,
                        ranged: stock.ranged,
                        inStock: stock.quantity > 0 ? true : false
                    }
                    );
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: You could use [mergeAll](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeAll) to make your code more *elegant*, but it won't make it more *efficient*: you'll still have many HTTP requests sent and that is what makes the code inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better not to do async actions in the `.subscribe()` which might also error. You can better have these calls embedded in your Rx stream so you can do error handling and things like concurrency control:

```
this.storeService.fetchStores(this.currentCoordinates)
  .mergeMap(_ => _) /* emit all values from the stores array as separate values in the rx stream */
  .mergeMap(
    store => this.stockService.fetchStockResults(store.ean, store.id))
      .catch(err => Rx.Observable.of({ ean: -1, range: false, quantity: -1})),
    (store, stock) => ({
                        storeObject: store,
                        ean: stock.ean,
                        ranged: stock.ranged,
                        inStock: stock.quantity > 0 ? true : false
                    }),
    10 /* concurrency; how many in-flight requests do you want?*/
  )
  .toArray()
  .subscribe(stockResults => console.log(stockResults));
```

Comment: /* concurrency; how many in-flight requests do you want?*/ not sure that I understand the question so  I don't have an opinion on. I am happy to go with a recommendation.

Comment: The mergeMap operator lets you optionally configure how many streams it concurrently merges, effectively giving you a configureable amount of http calls you will do concurrently. Totally depends on your architecture / bottlenecks in infra. See what works for you (10/50/...?)

Comment: Thanks, I will experiment. However, am struggling with the syntax from line 5. Looks like catch is suppose to take two arguments but looks like you may have extra closing bracket at line 5?

Comment: The second closing bracket is for the `Rx.Observable.of`. catch only takes one argument, see http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-catch

Comment: Yes I can see now. Then you got a coma followed by a function? This is second argument for mergeMap?

Comment: MergeMap takes an optional second argument, the `resultSelector` in which you get the input argument combined with every output value of the MergeMap so you can combine those